# software for database design and modification?

Tags: sql, database-design

I'm asking advice about a software for design and update a database.

I'm using ERStudio, and I like it, it generate the SQL scripts to design the tables.

But what I'd like to do is, with a software like ERStudio, to update the database structure too from scripts.

I mean; I generate the database, a put data on it, then I need to do some redesign... I don't want to delete the database populated and start over; I want the software to generate some "alter table" scripts and preserve the data when it's possible.

Does anyone know a software to do this?

Regards!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out [Red Gate's SQL Compare](http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-compare/?utm_source=google&utm_medium=cpc&utm_content=brand_aware&utm_campaign=sqlcompare&gclid=CKaNgIqJ56sCFQhN4Aod_B8AJw).

It can compare 2 databases (dev vs. prod) or snapshots of prior releases.